# Google App Engine: debugging Dashboard > Traffic > Sent

Tags: google-app-engine, traffic, outbound

I have an GAE app `PHP72, env: standard` which is hanging intermittently (once or twice a day for about 5 mins).

When this occurs I see a large spike in GAE dashboard's Traffic Sent graph.

I've reviewed all uses of `file_get_contents` and `curl_exec` within the app's scripts, not including those in `/vendor/`, and don't believe these to be the cause.

Is there a simple way in which I can review more info on these outbound requests?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get more details in that dashboard.  You're going to need to check your logs at the corresponding times.  Obscure things to check for:

- Cron jobs coming in at the same times
- Task Queues spinning up

Comment: I wasn't expecting anything more from the dashboard but had hoped to somehow view logs of outbound requests from a service.